# Sencha Cmd 7.2 not pick up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx4096m

Tags: sencha-cmd

Sencha Cmd 7.2 not picking up  `_JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms512m -Xmx4096m`, and it causes out of memory issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the **sencha.vmoptions** file inside the Sencha Cmd install directory.

The downside is that this has to be done on every build machine.

Comment: Are you sure this works? We just upgraded to Sencha Cmd 7.2 and got the impression is also no longer cares about -Xmx settings in sencha.vmoptions.

Comment: Unless it was a very big coincidence yes, the options did work for us on Cmd 7.2

Comment: It really seems to depend upon the exact Cmd 7.2 patch version. They seem to have fixed it in a later 7.2 release.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that along with the sencha.vmoptions, Sencha CMD also has the same options hard coded into the sencha script. On my Mac, I edited the ~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/7.2.0.x/sencha file and removed all of the -Xmx and -Xms arguments to the script and after that sencha.vmoptions were honored and my app compiled. The hard coded options are extremely low (i.e. -Xmx128m). I found this by comparing the 7.1 sencha script to the new 7.2. 
The location of the script may be different depending on the OS you're using.